# Шахматная доска на C# и проблемы с тернарным оператором

Tags: c#, массивы, тернарный-оператор, шахматы

*Хочу сделать доску в клетку по типу шахмат.
Написал 2 тернарных оператора.
Первый отвечает за нечетные строки и присваивает на четные клетки число 1.
Второй делает наоборот. Но код ругается на тернарные операции.*

```
int a = 10;
int b = 10;
Random mtrx=new Random();

int[,]matrix= new int [ a, b];
for(int i = 0; i<a; i++)
{
    
    for(int j = 0; j<b; j++)
    {
        matrix[j, i] =  (j%2!=0) ? (i%2==0) ? 1 : 0 ;
        matrix[j, i] =  (j%2==0) ? (i%2!=0) ? 1 : 0 ;

        Console.Write($"{matrix[i,j]} \t");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: А можете, пожалуйста, словами расписать ваш тернарный оператор?
Я правильно понимаю, что должно быть так:
Если j нечётное И i чётное то 1 иначе 0?

А второе условие:
Если j чётное И i нечётное то 1 иначе 0?

Comment: В тернарном операторе на каждый символ `?` должен быть символ `:`. У вас в каждой строке два `?` и один `:`. Вы, наверно, хотели написать: `matrix[j, i] =  (j%2!=0 && i%2==0) ? 1 : 0 ;` ?

Comment: Ваш способ помог, но вместо "&&" поставил ^.
При && или & присваивал через строку

Comment: `matrix[i, j] = (i ^ j) % 2;`

Answer (score 2):

`matrix[j, i] =  (j%2!=0) ? (i%2==0) ? 1 : 0 ;`

нету такого синтаксиса

---

Есть такой:

`matrix[j, i] =  (j % 2 != 0) ? 1 : 0 ;`

если условие в круглых скобках исполняется - то один.
Если не исполняется то 0.

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понимаю, вам достаточно будет такого условия:

```
matrix[j, i] = (j + i) % 2 != 0 ? 1 : 0;
```

Или ещё короче:

```
matrix[j, i] = (j + i) % 2;
```

А вообще тернарные операторы можно комбинировать, например, вкладывать:

```
условие1? (условие2 ? если_да2 : если_нет2) : если_нет1;
```

Но каждый из таких операторов должен быть со всеми элементами:

```
условие ? если_да : если_нет;
```

А у вас получилось что-то непонятное - два знака вопроса и одно двоеточие. И по логике двумя присваиваниями правильно сделать то, что вы хотите, не получится. Второе присваивание частично испортит вам результат первого присваивания.